# Bind Key of KeyBinding to Key Property

Tags: c#, wpf, key-bindings

I'm trying to bind the Key Property of a KeyBinding to a Key Property like this:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <local:InputBindingTrigger>
        <local:InputBindingTrigger.InputBinding>
            <KeyBinding Key="{Binding SettingsViewModel.PreviousHotkey}"/>
        </local:InputBindingTrigger.InputBinding>
        <cal:ActionMessage MethodName="FormKeyDown"/>
    </local:InputBindingTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

PreviousHotkey is a Property of type Key.

```
public Key PreviousHotkey
{
    get { return _previousHotkey; }
    set { _previousHotkey = value; }
}
```

As far as I understand, KeyBindings are application-wide, so it shouldnt matter which control has focus right?
When I execute I get the following error in the output:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 2 : Cannot find governing FrameworkElement or FrameworkContentElement for target element. BindingExpression:Path=SettingsViewModel.PreviousHotkey; DataItem=null; target element is 'KeyBinding' (HashCode=24311996); target property is 'Key' (type 'Key')
```

Also it does not seem to work.

How can I bind the Key property of a KeyBinding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

I've made a mistake in my solution, but since I am obliged to at least make an effort to provide a working solution, here is what I propose:

First of all, It seems that the custom `InputBindingTrigger` doesn't allow `Binding` when using `ActionMessage` property of `Caliburn.Micro`.

Therefore, since the `InputBindingTrigger` is already using `ICommand`, why not leave out the `Caliburn.Micro` and just use simple `KeyBinding` with commands?

**Xaml:**

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow">
    <Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="{Binding MyKey}" Command="{Binding MyCommand}" 
            CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Key}"/>
    </Window.InputBindings>
    <Grid>
        ...
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**MainWindow.cs:**

```
    public ICommand MyCommand { get; set; }

    Key _myKey ;
    public Key MyKey 
    {
        get
        {
            return _myKey;
        }
        set
        {
            _myKey = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("MyKey");
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        MyCommand = new KeyCommand(MyMethod);
        MyKey =  Key.F5;
    }

    public void MyMethod(object param)
    {
        var inputKey = param;
        // do something
    }
```

**Implementation of `KeyCommand`:** (*If you already haven't something like this implemented.*)

```
public class KeyCommand : ICommand
{
    Action<object> _execute;
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged = delegate { };
    public KeyCommand(Action<object> execute)
    {
        _execute = execute;
    }
    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public void Execute(object param)
    {
        _execute(param);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill check it once I get home! :)

Comment: Hm, I just tried this. The error is gone, but the KeyBinding does not seem to work. It doesnt trigger upon using the Key. I tried it without a binding, setting the Key in XAML and it also does not trigger, so it may be a different problem?

Comment: @TimKatheteStadler, sorry, I've made a mistake in my solution, please see my update.

Comment: One more question, any way to give the pressed key as parameter to the called method?

Comment: You can add `CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=Key}"` to your `KeyBinding`. This way your custom command has to be parametric (i.e. Action<object> _execute ) and also `MyMethod` would take parameters (e.g. `public void MyMethod(object param)`).

Comment: Thanks for your time, this is really helpful :)